# "SELECT TOP 10" USING SQLDBX

Tags: sql, db2

I tried running the following command in SQLDBX:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLE
```

But I get the following error:

> Sql014N An unexpected token "10" was located after "SELECT TOP". Mirrored tokens may include: "." SQLSTATE = 42601

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Updated the tags to DB2 based on the `Sql014N` error message.

Answer (score 3):

Your error message looks like it could be from DB2, hence I'd try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

---

Update: As Ranadip Dutta correctly mentioned in comments, DB2 `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` isn't deterministic unless combined with deterministic `ORDER BY`. This is as expected with many other DBMS as well (e.g. MS SQL Server, MySQL)

Comment: Also, I would mention that DB2 does not guarantee that the rows returned by FETCH FIRST N ROW ONLY are always the same N. So, you should have an order by clause.

Comment: @ranadip, that's correct. DB2 FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY, isn't deterministic, just like T-SQL "TOP x" and MySQL "LIMIT x" are not deterministic unless combined with _deterministic_ ORDER BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not better of VHU answer, but if you want first 10 rows order by writing rank (the deterministic method) into your table you can do it:

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE F1
ORDER BY RRN(f1)
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```